# Refresh SQLDataReader on button click

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqldatareader

Same as the title and using C#. 
Anyone know how to do this? I have a bunch of data read into a list box but the data doesn't refresh unless I restart the windows form. anyone know how to refresh it on a button click event?

```
   {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\John\Desktop\DB\DB\DB\setup.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
                ("SELECT PEOPLE " + "FROM Workers", conn);

                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(sdr["people"].ToString());
                    }

                    sdr.Close();
                }

                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
```

This is in windows form Load. So i'm looking to add a button on my form which refreshes the listbox items list

Comment: where did you put your code? Please commit part of your code!

Comment: all right sorry, i'll edit it

Comment: Put that code in a method(f.e. "getWorkers") and call it from form's load **and** button's click event-handlers.

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit of a newbie, i've created the class but how do I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Method

```
private void ShowPeople()
{
    // Put your code;
}
```

and then use the same in your button click

```
private void Button_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    ShowPeople();
}
```

Comment: You should at least have named the method better(f.e. `private IList<String> getWorkers()` or `private void addWorkers()`)

Answer (score 0):

To reload data over your sqldatareader (at least I guess you mean set by using the word "refresh") by pressing a button you simply have to access the database again with the same code you are already using. But the important point here is, that you are using a bad design. Therefore I point out an article (30 mins to read) which helped me a lot to improve my code and therefore got rid of code duplication.

Please read: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1

After you have read this article I will promise you that you will have a better understanding of how you have to access data in the database within your application

Comment: Why is `"SELECT PEOPLE " + "FROM Workers"` open for SQL-Injection? There's not even one parameter in this sql query. It's the same as `SELECT PEOPLE FROM Workers` (what OP should use to avoid misunderstandings).

Comment: Thanks for the tips ^^. @TimSchmelter how do I call the method i've just created from form load and the button click?